# How to update power-shell to 5.1 remotely using power-shell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have been assigned a task recently to update our power-shell to version 5 on all our platform. I have been able to detect which servers need to be updated but at the moment I am stuck with actually updating it. I can run the silent installer but it doesn't do anything.

```
If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 5){
    LogError "The following **** shall be updated: $($Global:setupConfiguration["GENERAL SETTINGS"]["CASINO_LOCATOR_NAME"])"

    $fileName = "Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu"
    $filePath = "C:\Temp\"
    $remoteFilePath = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\$fileName"
    LogMessage $filePath
    LogMessage $remoteFilePath

    if(!(Test-Path -Path $filePath )){
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $filePath
    }

    Copy-Item -Path $remoteFilePath  -Destination $filePath


    Start-Process "C:\Temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu" "/q /norestart" -Wait
}
```

Note i tried using dism.exe.

```
Invoke-Command{
    dism.exe /online /add-package /PackagePath:C:\Temp\KB3191564-x64.cab /norestart
    #Remove-Item c:\temp\KB3191564-x64.cab
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 6.3.9600.17031
Error: 11
You cannot service a running 64-bit operating system with a 32-bit version of DISM. 
Please use the version of DISM that corresponds to your computer's architecture.
```

Comment: Use WSUS and deploy the patch properly.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The servers are not in domain.

Comment: Then they shouldn't be in the environment 

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 My company uses The rAG (Rollout Automation Gear) is a tool that facilitates the remote execution of actions in one or multiple  servers, for that I need to deploy a PS Script.

Comment: Is the server 64bit or 32 bit? The error indicates that it is probably 32.

Comment: You should log your actions: `wusa.exe package.msu /quiet /norestart /log:C:\TEMP\WMF.evtx`

Comment: @EBGreen The server is running on 64-bit OS.

Comment: The next question is whether script is being run in a 32bit or 64bit powershell session.

Comment: @EBGreen I think you cracked the case.. will check tomorrow.

Comment: add a code to detect pc architecture and if else statement to install 32 bit vs 64 bit

Comment: $architecture=gwmi win32_processor | select -first 1 | select addresswidth
if ($architecture.addresswidth -eq "64"){
    your statement goes like this for 64bit
}
elseif ($architecture.addresswidth -eq "32"){
   your statement goes here for 32 bit
}

Comment: @Aravinda thank you! I uploaded the final version of my code :)

Answer (score 0):

To update the resolution to my question was as following :

```
If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 5) {
LogError "The following casino shall be updated: 
$($Global:setupConfiguration["GENERAL SETTINGS"]["CASINO_LOCATOR_NAME"])"

$fileName = "KB3191564-x64.cab"
$filePath = "C:\Temp\"
$remoteFilePath = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\$fileName"
LogMessage $filePath
LogMessage $remoteFilePath

  if(!(Test-Path -Path $filePath )){
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $filePath }

Copy-Item -Path $remoteFilePath  -Destination $filePath  

#Start-Process "C:\Temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu" "/q /norestart" 
-Wait

$architecture=gwmi win32_processor | select -first 1 | select addresswidth  
if 
($architecture.addresswidth -eq "64") { Invoke-Command  {
dism.exe /online /add-package /PackagePath:C:\Temp\KB3191564-x64.cab 
/norestart
#Remove-Item c:\temp\KB3191564-x64.cab


 } } elseif 
 ($architecture.addresswidth -eq "32"){ throw "Error Message" }

}
```